# The entire page get loaded at the time of navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

At the time of navigation the entire page get loaded instead the particular component.

> Routes page:

```
       <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage}/>
            <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
            <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
            <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
            <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
        </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
```

> Navigation bar:

```
       <NavItem>
          <NavLink href="/">
            Home
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
        <NavItem>
          <NavLink
            href="/about-us"
          >
          About Us
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
```

> App.js:

```
         <BrowserRouter>
           <Route component={Routes}/>
         </BrowserRouter>
```

Usually when we clicks the navigation links in navigation bar it will provide the required component without loading the entire page here its loading the entire page.

> react version : 16.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using react-routers NavLink, If not try this,

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

<NavLink to="/about-us">About</NavLink>
```

> Note: the prop used is to not href

One more thing `<BrowserRouter/>` isn't required in App.js as you are using it inside the Routes component

Answer (score 0):

Place your navigation component on top or outside of `<Switch/>` component, so it's able to receive props as url and many others for navigation from it's parent(`<BrowserRouter/>`) and then just render what is inside of `<Switch/>`.

You could simplify your component like this:

```
        const Routes = (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <NavigationBar />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={LandingPage} />
                    <Route exact path="/contact" component={Contact} />
                    <Route exact path="/about-us" component={AboutUs} />
                    <Route exact path="/services" component={Services} />
                    <Route exact path="/products" component={Products} />
                </Switch>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
```

> Also try to avoid nesting `<BrowserRouter/>` inside another
>   `<BrowserRouter/>`.

Avoid navigation using `href` because you will flush all the running js code and then the whole page will be requested once again, to navigate with `React Router` you have to use nagivation through the `history` API, for this you have 2 options:

1. Semantically:
   importing `<Link/>` wherever you need

   ```
       import {Link} from "react-router-dom"
       ...
       <Link to="./new-url"/>
   ```
2. Programmatically:
   Pushing the new url to the history api

   ```
       this.props.history.push("./new-url")
   ```

> Remember: In order to make it work you need to pass props to the actual component.